# long many to many-database table: best performance practice

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a question about performance of my MYSQL database design.

Table A has a lot of records, say a million, and table B also has a million. There is another table C in which every record id of A is connected to every row in B and this connection has an additional value 1 or 0. So functionally speaking, every record in A has a boolean vector where B contains the 'variables' of the vector and 1 or 0 is the value. It's explained more graphically in the image on bottom.

Table C will have a lot of write and read actions (select all values from a record of A), so the the table is very actively used. And table C is really long, a million times a million rows.

- My first question is, will the length of the table give a performance
  issue? the database needs to be really fast.
- My second question is, if this is badly designed, whether there is a better design to achieve what i want. For instance I can think of storing the entire B vector of each A record inside of each row in A. Then table C will not be necessary. But it will make selecting, reading, writing much more difficult.

[image: table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table design is fine and shouldn't be a problem, because you access records via IDs which should be indexed. Depending on your typical queries you should also consider adding composite indexes (`c(a_id,b_id)`, `c(a_id,value)`, `c(b_id,value)`, `c(a_id,b_id,value)`).

However, as there exist only two states, 0 and 1, you may decide only to store one of them. I.e. if you store all state 1 records only, all pairs not in the table have state 0 then implicitly. This pays especially when the states are unevenly distributed (say 90% of the records have state 0 and only 10% have state 1) or you usually access only one of the states (e.g. you always look for 1s).

Comment: Get rid of C_id; it is a waste of space and it slows things down.  Instead, have `PRIMARY KEY(a_id, b_id)`.  And you will possibly need to access things in the other direction, so have `INDEX(b_id, a_id)`.  And, yes, get rid of `value`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Answer to your first question

> Millions of records in a table with multiple read and write won't be a
>   bottleneck if you are following best practices of mysql.
>
> Your engine should be innodb.
>
> Your select queries should not involve a full table scan.
>
> Your table should have desired indexes.

2. Answer to your second question

> You should look for all your possible use cases, because either way is
>   a good idea if a use case supports it.
>
> If you split your data across multiple tables than join operation is
>   to be performed if needed.